# Should redux-thunk manage loading and saving data on the device?

Tags: react-native, local-storage, redux-thunk

I am using redux-thunk in my react-native projects, and I am facing a situation that I don't know how it would be best handled.

When an action is dispatched (as a function, so redux-thunk handles it first), I need to do 2 things: first is to to update the Redux store with a value; second, is to save the value on the device using the local storage options (AsyncStorage, SecureStore from Expo, ect.).

In some other situations I need to retrieve the data from the device, and update the Redux store as well. Loading data asynchronously is the main purpose of using redux-thunk, so I guess it's fine.

However, should redux-thunk also manage the saving of data on the device?

As I see it, saving data is part of the main application logic; making redux-thunk save the data makes this task an application state logic, which kind of seems incorrect.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have launched many different react projects with `redux-thunk` handling `AsyncStorage` and i have not yet faced any major issues. I guess it would boil down to what you are more comfortable with; as it will run on the same thread either way.

From my personal experience i like keeping all my logic in the same place and not duplicate any code, which is one of the motivations of adding `redux-thunk` to your state management.

Finally, keep in mind that while you are loading and rendering you can always use a simple `dispatch` for a state i.e : isLoading` to handle all different loading and rendering async tasks.  (:

Lets see some code :

```
export const signin = (username, password) => {

    return async (dispatch, getState) => { 
        dispatch({type: SIGN_IN_START,  isLoading: true, })
        // please DONT use this in real life and make sure to encrypt username and passwords!
       // Use tokens, tokens are beautiful 
        await axios.get('http://someauth.com/user='.concat(username)}).then(async function (res) {

                if (res.data[0] !== null){
                    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@myData', JSON.stringify(res.data[0]))
                    dispatch({type: SIGN_IN_SUCESS, isLoading: false, })
                }
                else{
                    dispatch({type: SIGN_IN_FAILURE, isLoading: false,  error: err})
                }

            }).catch(function (err){
                dispatch({type: SIGN_IN_FAILURE, isLoading: false,  error: err})
            })
    }

}
```

for this example i could set `SIGN_IN_START` to set loading state to true and `SIGN_IN_SUCESS` or `SIGN_IN_FAILURE` to resume my application.

Comment: Do you use any particular method for handling saving data? For example, do you have some middleware that gets triggered upon some events? Or do you just call the data saving function directly (like AsyncStorage.setItem(...)) ?

As for asynchronous status, I am already using "status" variables and I update them as status progresses, that's a good idea :)

--EDIT: just saw your edit, I see you call the saving function directly. thanks for your contribution :)

Comment: thats the beauty with `redux-thunk` everything is state even functions, just create a your custom function to get triggered upon any event that gets changed by any variable. i added some code for clarification.

Comment: I have just posted less than 1 hour ago, maybe some other users will come later with a different opinion. I will choose an answer later, I hope you understand.